# Problem loading a specific website through Qt Webkit

Tags: python, webkit, pyqt, qtwebkit

I am currently using the following PyQt code to create a simple browser:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
web = QWebView()
web.load(QUrl("http://www.robeez.com"))
web.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Websites like google.com or stackoverflow.com work fine but robeez.com doesn't.  Does anyone with Webkit experience know what might be wrong? robeez.com works fine in a regular browser like Chrome or Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try [arora](http://code.google.com/p/arora/) (a very simple wrapping on top of QtWebKit); if it works, its your code. if it doesn't, its the website.

Comment: robeez.com doesn't work from arora either, I'm not sure what's so different about this website.

Comment: it does seem to work on Konqueror (which uses the original KHTML from which apple evolve WebKit).  I'd file a bug report to Qt.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason http://www.robeeez.com which I think redirects to rebeez.com DOES work.
In some cases rebeez.com sends out a blank index.html page, dillo and wget also receive 
nothing as does the qt45 demo browser. So is it the browser or the way the site is set up??

Answer (score 0):

Try sending the Accept-Language header also, it then works for me.