# QWebView not loading external CSS

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qwebview, pyside

I am using a QWebView to display some content and I want to use custom CSS to spruce up the output.  I found that I can use the `QWebSettings.setUserStyleSheetUrl()` method to load my own CSS into the view.  The `.css` file is in the same directory as my main program.

```
self.webview = QWebView(MainWindow)
self.webview.settings().setUserStyleSheetUrl(QUrl.fromLocalFile("myCustom.css"))
```

However, the custom stylings don't load when I add the content to the page using `setHtml()`.  I have tested that the CSS is properly applying to the HTML in a standard browser.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Qt, all paths to external files need to be **ABSOLUTE** paths, not relative ones.

To fix the problem, I add to make the following change:

```
path = os.getcwd()
self.webview.settings().setUserStyleSheetUrl(QUrl.fromLocalFile(path + "/myCustom.css"))
```

And everything worked correctly.  Hopefully this will help someone in the future and save them a few hours debugging.

Comment: For non-ASCII pathnames consider using `os.getcwdu()` instead. I also found that `os.getcwdu()` can return strangely encoded values on Mac OS-X, which needs to be normalized by `unicodedata.normalize('NFC', your_unicode_pathname)`.

Answer (score 1):

> In Qt, all paths to external files
>   need to be ABSOLUTE paths, not
>   relative ones.

That's not true. The code below works for me.

```
#include <QtCore>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QtWebKit>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QMainWindow mainWindow;

    QWebView* webView = new QWebView(&mainWindow);
    webView->settings()->setUserStyleSheetUrl(QUrl::fromLocalFile("google.css"));

    QFile source("google.html");
    source.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    webView->page()->mainFrame()->setHtml(QString::fromUtf8(source.readAll().constData()));

    mainWindow.setCentralWidget(webView);
    mainWindow.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

> The .css file is in the same directory
>   as my main program.

Relative paths are interpreted relative to the current working directory which need not be the same as executable's directory.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this, so I'll post my test snippet here; the snippet generates its own .html and .css file in the same directory as the python script; and the script was called from the same directory for testing.

At least in `python`/`PyQt4`, it seems that - indeed - it is *only* absolute paths that work with `setHtml`.

The test code can either:

- fail completely (completely blank [*in which case I really would have wished `QWebView` to spit out some error messages; found [How to get detailed error message when QTWebKit fails to load a page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7279046/how-to-get-detailed-error-message-when-qtwebkit-fails-to-load-a-page?rq=1), but cannot get it to work*]);
- show content without css style;
- or show the content styled:

[image: compare_qtwebkit-test.py]

The `setHtml` method seems to show styled text only with specification `c3`, where `file://` + absolute path is used. (*EDIT: just wanted to note that the suggestion in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1111422/277826), to "try [arora](http://code.google.com/p/arora/) (a very simple wrapping on top of QtWebKit); if it works, its your code. if it doesn't, its the website." was very helpful for double-checking behaviour*)

This is the setup the script was tested on:

```
$ lsb_release --description --codename 
Description:    Ubuntu 11.04
Codename:   natty

$ apt-show-versions -r python-qt4
python-qt4/natty uptodate 4.8.3-2
python-qt4-dbus/natty uptodate 4.8.3-2

$ apt-show-versions -r libqtwebkit4
libqtwebkit4/natty uptodate 2.1~really2.0.2-0ubuntu1

$ python --version
Python 2.7.1+
```

The script is:

**`qtwebkit-test.py`**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# portions from:
# http://pysnippet.blogspot.com/2010/01/more-fun-with-qwebkit.html

import sys
import os
from PyQt4 import QtCore
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import QtWebKit

global htmltext

def GenerateFiles():
  global htmltext

  print "GenerateFiles running"

  csstext = """
  body {
    background-color: #058;
    margin: 0px;
    color: red;
  }
  """

  css_file = open("test.css", "w")
  css_file.write(csstext)
  css_file.close()


  htmltextTop = """
  <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
  <html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  """

  htmltextBottom = """
  <title>qtwebkit-test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <h1>HEADING</h1>
  <p>Just to test ....</p>
  <p>.... and test some more</p>
  </body>
  </html>
  """

  cssopen = '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="'
  cssclose = '">'

  # c1
  cssfile = "test.css"
  # c2
  #~ cssfile = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)) + "/" + "test.css"
  # c3
  #~ cssfile = "file://" + os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)) + "/" + "test.css"
  # c4
  #~ cssfile = "qrc://" + os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)) + "/" + "test.css"
  # c5 (empty)
  #~ cssfile = ""

  cssline = cssopen + cssfile + cssclose

  #~ htmltext = htmltextTop + htmltextBottom      # without css
  htmltext = htmltextTop + cssline + htmltextBottom

  html_file = open("test.html", "w")
  html_file.write(htmltext)
  html_file.close()


def main():
  global htmltext

  GenerateFiles()
  qApp = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

  webView = QtWebKit.QWebView()

  # l1
  #~ webView.load(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile("test.html")) # fails

  # l2
  #~ webView.load(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile("./test.html")) # fails

  # l3
  #~ webView.load(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)) + "/" + "test.html")) # this works with #c1-#c3

  # setHtml
  #print htmltext
  webView.setHtml(htmltext) # works with #c3 (rest are unstyled)

  webView.show()
  webView.resize(500, 400)
  webView.setWindowTitle(__file__)
  sys.exit(qApp.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```