# How to run PyQt4 with flash web page?

Tags: python, pyqt4, flash

I use this very simple python script [Problem loading a specific website through Qt Webkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111267/problem-loading-a-specific-website-through-qt-webkit) to display a web page. It works well, but it doesn't detect my installed libflashplayer.so on linux x86_64 (that displays http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash/ URL) . What can I do to be able to run flash web pages ? (flash works well with all my classics browsers)

Regards,
sputnick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable the plugins explicitly with:

```
QWebSettings.globalSettings().setAttribute(QWebSettings.PluginsEnabled, True)
```